# Debugging Issue on Assemble Code by using GDB

Tags: debugging, gdb

I tried to use gdb to debug the Assemble code but got error message,it said:

```
(gdb) run Starting program: /root/assembler_program/bsawp.o
/bin/bash: /root/assembler_program/bsawp.o: cannot execute binary file
```

The code:

```
.section .text
.globl _start
_start:
nop
movl 0x12345678 ,  %ebx
bswap %ebx    
movl $1 , %eax
int $0x80
```

Then I use gdb :

```
(gdb) break *_start+1
Breakpoint 1 at 0x400079
(gdb) run
Starting program: /root/assembler_program/bsawp

Breakpoint 1, 0x0000000000400079 in _start ()
(gdb) step
Single stepping until exit from function _start,
which has no line number information.

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000400079 in _start ()
```

Could you please provide any hint and suggestion?

Thanks!
Best regards

Comment: You have two separate problems:
1) it would appear that you don't have a working, executable program, which is why the kernel complains via bash.
2) you have a segv due to some memory violation

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
Starting program: /root/assembler_program/bsawp.o
```

you are trying to run a relocatable object file. Don't do that.

You *must* link your object into an executable first. Something like this:

```
gcc -nostdlib -nostartfile test.s
```

Here:

```
Starting program: /root/assembler_program/bsawp
```

you apparently did link the `bsap.o` into an executable. The crash is happening here:

```
(gdb) x/i $pc
=> 0x400079 <_start+1>: mov    0x12345678,%ebx
```

This instruction is trying to load value from address `0x12345678`, into register. But that address does not point to a valid memory location.

You most likely meant for it to load a *constant* `0x12345678`, in which case the instruction you want is:

```
movl $0x12345678, %ebx
```

With that fix, I get expected:

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: /tmp/a.out 
[Inferior 1 (process 238270) exited with code 022]
(gdb) p/x 022
$1 = 0x12
```

Comment: Hello @Employed Russian,thanks for your comment.I use as -o destination_file source_file to get a destination file and then use ld -o exe_file destination_file to get a executable file.I used this method and I got the result normally,but I am confused this time when I programmed this Assembly code.